# infinite Datastructures in D

Tags: d, lazy-evaluation

I found examples of lazy evaluation of function arguments in D http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/lazy-evaluation.html

I´m wondering how to implement possible infinite Datastructures in D like it´s common behaviour of haskell´s lists.

Are there some Examples ?

What is the equivalent of the infinite fibonacci sequence:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Comment: Would something like http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_range.html#recurrence satisfy your condition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

check out how randoms are implemented for an example https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/random.d

but here's the fibonacci sequence

```
struct FiboRange{
    enum bool empty=false;//infinite range

    long prev=0,curr=1;//the state for next calculations

    @property long front(){
        return curr;//current value
    }

    void popFront(){//calculate the next value
        long tmp = curr;
        curr += prev;
        prev = tmp;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
recurrence!((s,n) { return s[n-1] + s[n-2]; })(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 9):

Arlen mentioned in a comment that the D version quickly overflows, because it doesn't use bigints. Fortunately, bigints are available as a library module, and are compatible with `recurrence`:

```
import std.bigint;
auto fibs = recurrence!"a[n-1] + a[n-2]"(BigInt(1), BigInt(1));
```

Answer (score 8):

This is basically the same thing as Mehrdad's answer but uses, in my opinion, slightly more readable syntax:

```
recurrence!"a[n-1] + a[n-2]"(1, 1)
```

Comment: personally I prefer `recurrence!q{a[n-1] + a[n-2]}(1, 1)` for strings representing code (for mixins and functors)

Comment: **Don't** use *any* kind of string for code, if you can help it (although if you *must*, I agree with @ratchet). Use a function literal instead -- it will catch errors better.

Comment: It is incredibly common practice to do exactly what eco did here with strings, and it's generally far more legible than either ratchet or Merhad's proposals IMHO. However, `recurrence` will take anything which is callable as a unary function with the correct types, so there are several options on how to give a function to `recurrence`, and you can pick whichever one you happen to prefer.

Comment: It would be so nice if D allowed you to pass expression (a sort of macro, not the value from evaluating the expression) as parameters to templates.

Comment: Sadly, the D version quickly overflows, but the Haskell version continues to print Fibonacci numbers because it uses Big int.

Comment: @Arlen gmfawcett provided [an answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512574/infinite-datastructures-in-d/6654882#6654882) that uses and works with BigInt.

Answer (score 4):

[ratchet freak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512574/infinite-datastructures-in-d/6512725#6512725) covered Fib.

Because it is implemented as a value type, taking copies of it will act as expected. This will also work for any "data structure" (as the OP was using it, not a struct) of any size where a finite amount of storage and a transition operation can define the reachable domain from any point.